# dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0006' near line 0: newline in field name `#padding'

Tags: dpkg

I installed xubuntu, after reboot it was installing updates, I stopped it by clocking the close button. Then apt-get didn't work so I removed the file `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` which I don't know if I should have done. Now when I want to install something with apt-get I get

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

When I run that I get

```
dpkg: error: parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0006' near line 0: newline in field name `#padding'
```

And I can't install anything. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easily just delete that file error

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/0006
```

then run again

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```